# JsonCovert.DeserializeObject<T> is loading the object type but none of the Json Fields

Tags: c#, json

I am new to coding in C# and serializing Json objects.

I am trying to use Json.net to load in a file saved as a json object ("filename.json")

Below is the code I am trying to use to load it in. I have looked around here on the best way to load in a Json object and this appears to be the consensus. The object I am trying to load in is defined later in the class. I used the http://json2csharp.com/ tool to create a class from the Json file.

```
List<DashboardList> dashboardList = null;
        DashboardList db = new DashboardList();
        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileLoc);
            string jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            db = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DashboardList>(jsonString);
```

The Json object is as follows.

```
{
  "DashboardList": {
"Dashboard": {
  "id": "1",
  "title": "Executive Dashboard",
  "description": "Generic Dashboard",
  "allowableMemberTypes": "",
  "Pages": {
    "Page": [
```

the rest of Json is very long and probably not important.

when I run the code I get a Dashboard object with null fields.

EDIT:

```
 public class Dashboard
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string allowableMemberTypes { get; set; }
        public Pages Pages { get; set; }
    }

    public class DashboardList
    {
        public Dashboard Dashboard { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Show us the definition of `DashboardList` and `Dashboard`.

Comment: Your root object must be something that has property `DashboardList`

Comment: What does that mean? Is it ok for the root object to be titled DashboardList? (Which I think with the way I have it set up now it is)

Comment: Thanks a lot @I4V I figured it out you were right I needed the root object thanks for your help. Should anyone else look at this what needs to be changed look at the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity:

```
        RootObject ro = new RootObject();
         try
        {

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileLoc);
            string jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            ro = ser.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonString);


       }
```

you need to add a reference to system.web.extensions in .net 4.0 this is in program files (x86) > reference assemblies> framework> system.web.extensions.dll and you need to be sure you're using just regular 4.0 framework not 4.0 client